# Freezing unauthorized tokens

Tags: transactions

Account A issued and transferred asset ABC to distributor account B
Account A was locked
account B was issued trust-lines from X, Y, Z to accept ABC tokens
transferred ABC to X, Y ,Z
X, Y, Z are bad actors and moved asset to account F
how do I freeze account F?
interestingly enough, even though account F is showing the balance
account B still showing a total amount of ABC that was issued.. like transfer didn't happen
Can you explain, did I make a mistake and never really transferred the asset to begin with, if yes, how come account F has a balance?
thank you so much..

Answer (score 2):

Most likely "Account B was issued trust-lines from X, Y, Z to accept ABC tokens." is where things got wrong, since trustlines don't have anything to do with distribution accounts.

I'm guessing that your X,Y,Z trustlines are for ABC issued from "Account B", and not from "Account A"

Comment: I guess The whole transaction was set up.in. Wrong way..Since XYZ was issued truslines from.B the distributor and not A.

Comment: Why then F is showing balance of tokens?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how or what might be happening, sharing address will definitely help us identify the issue or know the full case.

Just in case you are wondering, you can use the REVOCABLE flag to freeze the asset, why don't you try setting this as F is a bad actor.

Below is a quote from Stellar Docs - [Link](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html)

> **Requiring or Revoking Authorization**
>
> Accounts have several flags related to issuing assets. Setting the
>   AUTHORIZATION REVOCABLE flag allows you to freeze assets you issued in
>   case of theft or other special circumstances. This can be useful for
>   national currencies, but is not always applicable to other kinds of
>   assets.
>
> If your asset is special purpose or you’d like to control who can be
>   paid with it, use the AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED flag, which requires that
>   the issuing account also approves a trustline before the receiving
>   account is allowed to be paid with the asset.

Comment: Am I setting this from the issue account or disctubitor?

Comment: I though you had to set authorization required first..before you could revoke it?

Comment: UPON checking my issuing account had both flags authorization required and authorization revocable set to "true" but when i tried to run "allow trust " operation to revoke the trusline i was getting error message. Could it be that because i never allow the trus t to begin with hence i cant revoke it \? If so why the bad actor account is showing balance of my tokens?

Comment: THIS IS ACCOUNT F: GCT47BXQ2EEB4ULI3IKWAQ7B2VF33QDB6NYCB7PGX7A5MR4JFUZQIUJT Its holding my CBR tokens that they scammed from me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide us the addresses of these account **X, Y, Z, F**?

But here a quick remeber of how tokens works in stellar.

1. **DISTRIBUTOR** Add trust to **ISSUER**
2. **ISSUER** issues the asset and send them to **DISTRIBUTOR**
3. **X Y Z** add trust to **ISSUER**
4. **DISTRIBUTOR** send asset to **X Y Z**

So account **F** need to trust **ISSUER** first and then **X Y Z** can send him the new asset

Comment: Yes, if address is shared, that will be easier to debug.

Comment: F issued a trust to an Issuer by themselves.... Since the could find an asset issuer on Stellar..

Comment: I will provide the addresses of X,Y,Z,F. Later today.. I need to freeze those tokens..Thank you.

Comment: THIS IS ACCOUNT F:   GCT47BXQ2EEB4ULI3IKWAQ7B2VF33QDB6NYCB7PGX7A5MR4JFUZQIUJT Its holding my CBR tokens that they scammed from me.. Can you help me to freeze it?

Comment: You don't have to freeze it. Different Issuer = Different Coin, so you can't confuse assets with him because if your receiving account doesn't had trusted his scam address before receiving tokens he can't send them to you

Comment: But XYZ and F could always issue trustline to the account a. Why F is showing the balance of CBR?